# XSLT transformation of comma separated xml element

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have a xml doc like this example (with spaces as shown)

```
<block>
 <Text>FirstName: Bob, LastName: Smith, PhoneNumber: 12345</Text>
<block>
```

and would like to transform in an XSLT so the xml becomes

```
<block>
 <Text>
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <PhoneNumber>12345</Phonenumber>
 </Text>
<block>
```

Any help greatly appreciated, Many thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheet below uses a named recursive template as a tokenizer for the text content. It reads the first text before the comma and creates an element with the string before the semicolon, containing the string after the semicolon. Then it calls the method again with the string after the comma until no more commas are found and the last element is created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="block">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Text">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="','" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="separator"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                <xsl:element name="{substring-before($text, ':')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text, ': ')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{substring-before($text, ':')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, ': '), $separator)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, concat($separator, ' '))"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="','" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Cheers All, thanks for the suggestions,, unfortunaltely Iam constrained to use xslt 1.0  not 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Text">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(text(), ',')">
            <xsl:element name="{normalize-space(tokenize(.,':')[1])}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(tokenize(.,':')[2])"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

An **XSLT 2.0** solution that uses the **[tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)** function to split on '`,`' and generate the desired content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Text">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',\s?')">
                <xsl:element name="{substring-before(current(), ': ')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ': ')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An **XSLT 1.0** solution that uses a recursive template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Text">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="split"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="val" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($val) and contains($val, ':')">
            <xsl:variable name="item" select="substring-before(concat($val, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:element name="{substring-before($item, ': ')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($item, ': ')"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="val" select="substring-after($val, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one that uses XSLT 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Text">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ', ')">
                <xsl:element name="{substring-before(., ':')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ': ')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML, the output is:

```
<block>
    <Text>
        <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <PhoneNumber>12345</PhoneNumber>
    </Text>
</block>
```